# XML unmarshalling to java objects

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

XML response

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <Film>
  <film_id>1</film_id> 
  <title>ACADEMY DINOSAUR</title> 
  <description>xxx</description> 
  <length>86</length> 
  <image_id>1</image_id> 
-  <image>
   <image_id>1</image_id> 
   <name>1.jpg</name> 
   <size>408307</size> 
   <type>.jpg</type> 
   <content>base64 byte</content>
   </image>
 </Film>
```

I have created pojo classes for Film and Image.

Film.java

```
public class Film {
    private String film_id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String length;
    private String image_id;
    private Image image;
//setter and getter methods
}
```

Image.java

```
public class Image {
    private int image_id;
    private String name;
    private int size;
    private String type;
    private byte[] content;
//setter and getter methods
}
```

Please help I am new to this and I should use JAXB.

**SOLUTION:**

I have added

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "film")
public class Film {
    private int film_id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private int length;
    private int image_id;
    private Image image;
}
```

on the getter method of Image, I have added @XMLElement(name="image").

On Image class I have added an annotation @XmlRootElement(name = "image"), which gives me what I wanted.

Comment: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"film"). Expected elements are (none).....this is the error I get when I made an attempt.  public void unmarshaling(String output) throws JAXBException {
  InputStream is = new StringBufferInputStream(output);
  JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Film.class);
  Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
  Film film = (Film) u.unmarshal(is);

Comment: Why don't you edit your question instead of writing hard to read comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing required to get your use case to work is to add an `@XmlRootElement` annotation on the `Film` class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Film")
public class Film {
    private String film_id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String length;
    private String image_id;
    private Image image;
}
```

**The Other Part of Your Solution**

> on the getter method of Image, I have added @XMLElement(name="image").
>
> On Image class I have added an annotation @XmlRootElement(name =
>   "image"), which gives me what I wanted.

Neither of these steps are required to map your particular use case.

Comment: Yes, it does not require @XMLElement(name="image"). I have a warning even if I embedded @XMLElement(name="image") tag to my class. This did not affect my output. But what is this error about?                                                            ** WARNING: duplicate class definition bug occured? Please report this : serviceone/client/entity/Image$JaxbAccessorM_getContent_setContent_[B
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "serviceone/client/entity/Image$JaxbAccessorM_getContent_setContent_[B" in class file serviceone/client/entity/Image$JaxbAccessorM_getContent_setContent_[B **

Comment: @Koushik - The exception you are seeing is specific to the JAXB reference implementation and not JAXB (JSR-222) in general.  I would recommend reporting the issue at the following link:  http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB/

Answer (score -2):

Try converting your arrays to list on dublicating classes (worked for me)

As i see byte[]    ->   List < Byte>

Comment: List<Byte> is not a good idea. It would generate one element per byte in resulting XML. In most cases this is not what you want and it would blow up the size of the XML.